# select_from_array field in laravel backpack not showing correct values in the form

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have added one new field called **vendor** on the User Model class,

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory;
    use CrudTrait;
    use HasRoles;
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'vendor',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'password' => 'hashed',
        'select_from_array'     => 'array',
    ];
}
```

and updated the UserCrudController as follows

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Backpack\PermissionManager\app\Http\Controllers\UserCrudController as BackpackUserCrudController;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanelFacade as CRUD;

class UserCrudController extends BackpackUserCrudController
{
    public function setupListOperation()
    {
        // This takes care to add all fields from the package. If you need some field removed you could use CRUD::removeField
        parent::setupListOperation();
        CRUD::field([   // select_from_array
            'name'        => 'vendor',
            'label'       => "Vendor/Company",
            'type'        => 'select_from_array',
            'options'     => $this->getVendor(),
            'allows_null' => true,
            'allows_multiple' => true, // OPTIONAL; needs you to cast this to array in your model;
        ])->after('name'); 
    }

    public function setupCreateOperation()
    {
        // This takes care to add all fields from the package. If you need some field removed you could use CRUD::removeField
        parent::setupCreateOperation();
        CRUD::field([   // select_from_array
            'name'        => 'vendor',
            'label'       => "Vendor/Company",
            'type'        => 'select_from_array',
            'options'     => $this->getVendor(),
            'allows_null' => true,
            'allows_multiple' => true, // OPTIONAL; needs you to cast this to array in your model;
        ])->after('name');
    }
    public function setupUpdateOperation()
    {
        // This takes care to add all fields from the package. If you need some field removed you could use CRUD::removeField
        parent::setupUpdateOperation(); 
       
        CRUD::field([   // select_from_array
            'name'        => 'vendor',
            'label'       => 'Vendor/Company',
            'type'        => 'select_from_array',
            'options'     => ['one' => 'One', 'two' => 'Two'],
            'allows_null' => true,
            'allows_multiple' => true, // OPTIONAL; needs you to cast this to array in your model;
        ])->after('name');
        
        // Any other fields that you need
    }

    public function getVendor(){
        return \App\Models\Vendors::all()->keyBy('vendor_name')->pluck('vendor_name', 'vendor_name')->toArray();
    }
}
```

I am using **select_from_array** Field to show data on the form on s**etupUpdateOperation()**
It displays as below screenshot,
When I save the form,the data are saved in the database in the below format

```
["one","two"]
```

But does not show the values in the form correctly, but the data are saved, I believe there is a rendering issue that I cannot figure out. Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hello chanz i try it on demo project and work as expected.

[image]

Controller

```
[ // select_from_array
                'name'              => 'select_from_array',
                'label'             => 'Select_from_array (no relationship, 1-1 or 1-n)'.backpack_free_badge(),
                'type'              => 'select_from_array',
                'options'           => ['one' => 'One', 'two' => 'Two', 'three' => 'Three'],
                'allows_null'       => true,
                'tab'               => 'Selects',
                'allows_multiple'   => true, // OPTIONAL; needs you to cast this to array in your model;
                'wrapperAttributes' => ['class' => 'form-group col-md-6'],
            ],
```

Model

```
protected $casts = [
        'select_from_array'     => 'array',
    ];
```

DB

```
["two","three"]
```

My versions:

```
### PHP VERSION:
PHP 8.2.8 (cli) (built: Jul  8 2023 07:09:59) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.8, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.2.8, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

### LARAVEL VERSION:
10.15.0.0

### BACKPACK PACKAGE VERSIONS:
backpack/backupmanager: v5.0.0
backpack/basset: 1.0.2
backpack/crud: 6.0.6
backpack/demo: dev-main
backpack/editable-columns: 3.0.1
backpack/filemanager: 3.0.2
backpack/generators: v4.0.2
backpack/logmanager: v5.0.0
backpack/medialibrary-uploaders: 1.0.1
backpack/menucrud: v4.0.1
backpack/newscrud: v5.0.0
backpack/pagemanager: 3.2.0
backpack/permissionmanager: 7.0.0
backpack/pro: 2.0.9
backpack/revise-operation: 2.0.0
backpack/settings: 3.1.0
backpack/theme-coreuiv2: 1.1.4
backpack/theme-coreuiv4: 1.0.5
backpack/theme-tabler: 1.0.6
```